# Propulsion or Space Elevator

Tags: technology, science-fiction, engineering

In a sci fi setting I'm writing, gravity can be easily controlled and gravity propulsion is used to push starships through space. I had the idea of space elevators being used to get on/off Earth but if they could negate gravity, couldn't they just take off with little effort?

Comment: I think you answered your own question there. If they can negate gravity why bother with the enormous expense and material cost to build a glorified elevator?

Comment: The big question is about energy, does the gravity drive still obey the conservation of energy, does it require significant energy to lift the craft off the surface of the planet.

Comment: It's impossible to determine energy requirements of something that is not known to exist even theoretically, of which an anti-grav drive (aka an type of inertialess drive) is one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why have an elevator at all. If I make a box and put a gravity drive on it I can go up as fast as I want. Or I could make a column of 0 gravity or reverse gravity that I can float things up.

Comment: Well that's what I mean. I had originally thought of having space elevators but reconsidered when I realized that it wouldn't work with the setting

Comment: But that column is where its at right? If you need to get something on or off the planet, having a gravity column somewhere is ideal as it would mean anything can be moved up or down rather than "just" things with a drive attached. This column (the elevator) would then just turn into a distribution node as items are pushed down other gravity tubes across the surface. The elevator would be key in fast and efficient transport over ships moving everywhere.

Answer (score 4):

Yes.

However, if you are looking for a reason why the gravity propulsion does not work on the surface of a planet, there are some possibilities:

1. Gravity propulsion works by creating a gravitational "cone" pulling the ship, with some reasonably large (kilometers, hundreds of kilometers) reach. Turning it on the surface of the planet would pull the upper crust, chunk of lithosphere or whatever. At the very least there would be gigantic planetquakes.
2. The propulsion works by directionally negating Mach principle, and needs a reasonably homogeneous inertial pull from all the directions. Being near a planet completely overwhelms the influence of distant galaxies.
3. It emits powerful gravitational waves. Not a problem in an interstellar space, but again, giant planetquakes if happens on the planetary surface.

Answer (score 2):

A transportation system that transports itself is less efficient than one that doesn't. Consider an electric car vs. a subway train. One of the big problems with electric cars is the need to carry large, heavy batteries, which eats into your efficiency - some of your effort is spend moving the things that allow you to move, rather than doing useful work. But if your car followed a track, like a train does, you could draw power from the track itself. The batteries are still *there*, but since they're not moving, you're not wasting energy moving them.

Likewise, a space elevator, or similar infrastructure, provides a way to externalize the equipment your ships need to travel to orbit. As a result, the equipment moving things to orbit doesn't have to move *itself* to orbit, and so does not waste as much energy doing so.

If your ships are designed for both surface-to-orbit and orbit-to-orbit operations (as opposed to having dedicated ships for both roles, and moving people and cargo between them) you also aren't wasting even more energy carrying the thrusters needed to reach orbit all the way to your destination planet. You can mitigate this problem with staging, of course, but that involves large chunks of rocket being thrown away at regular intervals, which impacts your reusability.

With that said, your stationary surface-to-orbit infrastructure doesn't need to resemble a "conventional" space elevator. In particular, if the nature of your gravity effect allows for it, I could see a "corridor" of anti-gravity that ships use to take off instead of a physical elevator. The efficiency argument doesn't change (even if your anti-gravity equipment isn't affected by gravity, it still has mass, and it will still be more efficient not to send it into orbit all the time) but the nature of the "elevator" does.

Comment: I had an idea like that. Like, the idea of a giant gravity lift opposed to a tradtional space elevator

Answer (score 1):

**The simplest Answer - COST**

All gravity drives are power hogs. In other words it takes a great deal of electrical power to generate useful, sustained acceleration. Mainly because the 'conversion' rate (e.g.mega-watts to Gs) is very low. The efficiency of the conversion rate might even drop of at higher accelerations rates.

This means a large ship transporting significant mass needs large (probably multiple) fusion reactors to generate significant thrust. And sustained 1 G plus accelerations which is what you need for orbital transfers *are* high acceleration rates. (In fact there's no compelling reason for a ship to accelerate at 1 G or higher in space because lower accelerations will let you reach high velocities quite quickly.)

In addition as others have mentioned the drive is a 'field' effect which means it impacts on *all* mass around the generator and, like Gravity itself it obeys the **Inverse Square Law**. This means that while the effect drops of with distance any field generated by a drive effects/places stress on objects out to a considerable distance. This means the while you could take off from ground level there are significant local impacts including taking a chunk of the atmosphere with you every time you do it. So while it *can* be done it just not practicable.

Which leaves you with  a simple, low power method of getting mass into orbit. The initial capital costs (building the elevators) are large but the operating costs (compared to ships) are tiny and they have a long working life (generations) if maintained properly.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the Space Elevator was constructed before the advent of the Gravity Drive and it's just cheaper to maintain it.

Besides to construct the planned artificial planetary ring structure the 3 space elevators will be highly useful in its malignance and construction.